# display images in model lightbox from javascript json

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, json

I have a script I'm playing with that pulls images from a subreddit. I would like to display the images in a model lightbox once clicked on. 
The images are called using the 'id' images, like so:

**`<a href="" id="images">`**

Is there a way to display the images in a model from the a tag? Or am I on the wrong track?

This is a script I found and have been playing around with to further my casual learning, my javascript skills are still basic so apologies if I'm missing the correct terminology but would be grateful to be shown in the right direction.

```
$.getJSON('http://www.reddit.com/r/cats/.json?jsonp=?&show=all&limit=300', function (data) {
$.each(data.data.children, function (i, item) {
    IsValidImageUrl(item.data.url, function (url, isvalid) {
        if (isvalid) {
            $('<img/>').attr('src', item.data.url)
                .width(500)
                .appendTo('#images');
        }
    });
});
```

});

```
function IsValidImageUrl(url, callback) {
var img = new Image();
img.onerror = function () {
    callback(url, false);
};
img.onload = function () {
    callback(url, true);
};
img.src = url;
```

}

Comment: You might look for a lightbox library like Fancybox.